# array.reduce and null values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am developing a javascript-based application, therein I have an array as below:

```
[-12.66, 268.2, 48.99, -1264.5, 20550, 91.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9235.5, 1500, 0, 0, 18.99, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

now I want to do cumulative summation of below error until it returns null value, once it has started reading null value it should return null from there or should return as it is and should not do cumulative summation from there.

I have done as below using `array.reduce`:

```
let resultArray=[];
array1.reduce(function (acc, curr, index) {  return resuleArray[index] = acc + curr }, 0); 
// here array1 is source array.
```

However, this returns as below

```
[-12.66, 255.54, 304.53, -959.97, 19590.03, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 28916.73, 30416.73, 30416.73, 30416.73, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72, 30435.72];
```

What I would like to have is like below :

```
[-12.66, 255.54, 304.53, -959.97, 19590.03, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 19681.23, 28916.73, 30416.73, 30416.73, 30416.73, 30435.72, 30435.72, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
```

Please note that I will always have trailing values as null.

Comment: you should test if curr or acc is null

Comment: Why are you using array.reduce? Reduce is typically used to process the array and return a single value. I think a for loop is more convenient here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, check if `curr` is `null`.

```js
const array1 = [-12.66, 268.2, 48.99, -1264.5, 20550, 91.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9235.5, 1500, 0, 0, 18.99, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

let resultArray = [];
array1.reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
  const sum = acc + curr;
  if (curr === null) {
    resultArray[index] = null;
  } else {
    resultArray[index] = sum
  }
  return sum;
}, 0);

console.log(resultArray);
```

This way even if you put a number after some `null` values it will continue with the cumulative summation

Comment: excellent this has worked for me.

Comment: why mutating the array? and why `reduce`?

Comment: @NinaScholz, why did you downgraded my question ?

Answer (score 0):

You need just to modify a little bit your code like this:

```js
array1.reduce(function (acc, curr, index) {  
  return resultArray[index] = curr !== null ? acc + curr : null 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over the sum and add unil the value is `null`.

```js
const
    data = [-12.66, 268.2, 48.99, -1264.5, 20550, 91.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9235.5, 1500, 0, 0, 18.99, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    result = data.map((sum => v => sum === null || v === null
        ? sum = null
        : sum += v
    )(0));

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Typical Nina. It takes time to understand her answer . At least that is how I feel. What does the `0` in `.... : sum += v)(0));`?

Comment: @MaikLowrey, it call the function and sets `sum` to zero and returns a new function for mapping.

Comment: Merci Nina. Ok tht is the initial value. like in reduce the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**Insert null in rest of the index once null is interpreted**

```js
const array1 = [-12.66, 268.2, 48.99, -1264.5, 20550, 91.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9235.5, 1500, 0, 0, 18.99, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
let resultArray = [];
let isNullInterpreted = false;
const output = array1.reduce(function (acc, curr, index) {
  isNullInterpreted = isNullInterpreted || curr == null;
  return resultArray[index] = isNullInterpreted ? null : acc + curr;
}, 0);
console.log(resultArray);
console.log(output);
```

**Stop iterating the loop once null is interpreted**

```js
const array1 = [-12.66, 268.2, 48.99, -1264.5, 20550, 91.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9235.5, 1500, 0, 0, 18.99, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
let resultArray = [];
let isNullInterpreted = false;
const output = array1.reduce(function (acc, curr, index) {
  isNullInterpreted = isNullInterpreted || curr == null;
  if (!isNullInterpreted) {
    resultArray[index] = acc + curr;
  }
  return resultArray[resultArray.length - 1]
}, 0);
console.log(resultArray);
console.log(output);
```